# How to get current platform(base/mobile) in SugarCRM logic hook?

Tags: sugarcrm

I need to know at any time what is the platform user is using: a mobile app or desktop web browser

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the current platform using

```
$platform = empty($_SESSION['platform']) ? 'base' : $_SESSION['platform'];
```

Values:

- `base` - *default*, used for regular web browser sessions
- `mobile` - the official mobile app / mobile mode
- `portal` - for Sugar (Enterprise/Ultimate/Sell/Serve) user portal sessions
- `opi` - the official MS Outlook SugarCRM plugin
- `lpi` - the official Lotus/IBM/HCL SugarCRM plugin

If you want to allow additional custom platform values, you can add them in *Administration* -> *Configure API Platforms* (in *Developer Tools* section)

see https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/10.0/Ent/Administration_Guide/Developer_Tools/#Configure_API_Platforms